# How can I add an interface with delegate implementations to a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, delegates, refactoring

What is the fastest way in Eclipse to implement a new interface and generate delegate implementations to an existing class?

For instance given an existing class `Foo`, suppose I want it to implement `Iterator<Integer>` using a delegate `Iterator<Integer>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add the delegate field `Iterator<Integer>` and the `implements Iterator<Integer>` to `foo` as follows:

   ```
   public class Foo implements Iterator<Integer> {
      Iterator<Integer> iterator;
   }
   ```
2. Select the source menu and then "Generate Delegate Methods".
3. Check the iterator box and click OK.  The resulting code will look as follows (depending on your formatting settings).

   ```
   public class Foo {
      Iterator<Integer> iterator;

      public boolean hasNext() { return iterator.hasNext(); }
      public Integer next() { return iterator.next(); }
      public void remove() { iterator.remove(); }
   }
   ```