# Generate a Forwarding implementation of an interface in Java

Tags: java, ant, code-generation

I have a specific interface say `InterfaceX` and a simple delegating decorator implementation which only delegates to the decorated interface.
( Following similar pattern in [Effective Java](https://github.com/marhan/effective-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/effectivejava/examples/chapter04/item16/ForwardingSet.java) ).
Different classes can then extend the `ForwardingInterfaceX` and implement only specific methods instead of all the methods in the interface.

e.g.

```
interface InterfaceX
{
   public void foo();
   public SomeOtherObject bar();
}

public class ForwardingInterfaceX implements InterfaceX
{
    private final InterfaceX decorated;

    public ForwardingInterfaceX(InterfaceX decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void foo()
    {
        decorated.foo();
    }

    public SomeOtherObject bar()
    {
        return decorated.bar();
    }
}

/** Only overrides the bar method **/
public class AnotherInterfaceXImplementation extends ForwardingInterfaceX
{
    private final InterfaceX decorated;

    public AnotherInterfaceXImplementation(InterfaceX decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public SomeOtherObject bar()
    {
        // Some Code
        // More Code
        return decorated.bar();
    }
}
```

I do not control changes in `InterfaceX`.
So far I've hand coded `ForwardingInterfaceX` but with every change in `InterfaceX`, I need to modify `ForwardingInterfaceX` which is becoming tedious.

I searched quite a bit but could find Runtime proxy related libraries / tools which do not seem to be good enough for this case since I extend the generated `ForwardingInterfaceX` class for other classes ( like `AnotherInterfaceXImplementation` ) to extend.

Are there any tools that I can use to auto-generate `ForwardingInterfaceX` as part of the build process so that it automatically keeps up with any changes in `InterfaceX`.
I am interested in tools that can be integrated into a build environment like ant ( not Eclipse or other IDE based tools ).

Comment: i don't see a reason for that. an interface is like a contract about a given functionality so any change in it should break your build. if there a things change without notifiying the implementer, bad things can happen

Comment: I understand. This is for an internal product whose interface will change till the product is actually released for public consumption. Hence changing interfaces are a reality that I need to live with.

Comment: You can use this eclipse technique to generate delegate methods:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500375/how-can-i-add-an-interface-with-delegate-implementations-to-a-class

Comment: Thanks! I know I can do that with Eclipse. Is there a way to trigger that from a command line since this will need to be part of the build process ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin capability of Ant to do that, and I'm not aware of any tools that generate arbitrary static proxy classes at build time.  If you need that, then you will probably need to write a custom Ant task that uses reflection to discover the methods of the target interface and then either writes a source file (with subsequent compilation) or generates the .class file.  If you've tried that and it isn't working, then you should ask a more specific question.

(Note that asking for recommendations for tools to use is [considered off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.  The site is intended to assist people with problems encountered after they've picked a tool.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ant based solution, but there's a library called Proxy Toys that should do what you want out of the box. It's also highly extendable if the default options aren't quite right.